# Selecting a Gate driver for IGBT

Tags: power-electronics, driver, motor-controller, igbt, pmsm

I have trouble choosing an IGBT gate driver for PMSM motor control application. Can someone help me with the procedure? I went through few papers and I'm stuck with finding the external and internal gate resistance. Is it mandatory to choose the gate driver based on the total resistance (internal + external), or can it be chosen by considering any other factors?